# Gulp Inject not injecting all my files. Adding only one main.scss file

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I am facing the issue from yesterday in gulp inject after rebuild, gulp-inject not injecting all my files. Adding only one main.scss file

Didn't changed anything in gulp styling task. Same code is working on my stage environment because I didn't rebuild the gulp.

Here is the code snippet.

```
  var injectFiles = gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/sass/**/_*.scss'),
    '!' + path.join(conf.paths.src, '/sass/theme/conf/**/*.scss'),
    '!' + path.join(conf.paths.src, '/sass/404.scss'),
    '!' + path.join(conf.paths.src, '/sass/auth.scss')
  ], {read: false});

  var injectOptions = {
    transform: function (filePath) {
      filePath = filePath.replace(conf.paths.src + '/sass/', '');
      return '@import "' + filePath + '";';
    },
    starttag: '// injector',
    endtag: '// endinjector',
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  return gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/sass/main.scss')
  ])
    .pipe($.inject(injectFiles, injectOptions))
    .pipe(wiredep(_.extend({}, conf.wiredep)))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe($.sass(sassOptions)).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Sass'))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer()).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Autoprefixer'))
    .pipe($.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve/app/')));
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Found that updating gulp-inject to version 5.0.3 fixes the issue.
https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/pull/258

Comment: This was a life savior :) Note that it doesn't work with Node10, but it works just fine with Node8. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Yepp, this fixed it nicely! However, I'm running Node10 and gulp-inject@5.0.3 and it works just fine for me injecting all the files as it should.

Comment: I have fixed it by adding post install script. Yes they updated the version later. Thanks for replying

Answer (score 4):

After evaluating the package-lock.json file. Following dependencies are required by gulp-inject

```
"gulp-inject": {
  "requires": {
    "arrify": "^1.0.1",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
    "event-stream": "^3.1.0",
    "group-array": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.0",
    "stream-to-array": "^2.3.0",
    "through2": "^2.0.1"
  }
},
```

After reverting version of all required dependencies one by one I am able to fix this. 
It is due to group-array@0.3.4 in my package-lock.json file.

```
"group-array": {
  "version": "0.3.4",
  "requires": {
    "arr-flatten": "^1.0.1",
    "for-own": "^0.1.4",
    "get-value": "^2.0.6",
    "kind-of": "^3.1.0",
    "split-string": "^1.0.1",
    "union-value": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

Fixed it by adding post install script in my package.json file

```
"postinstall": "npm i group-array@0.3.3 --save"
```